# Error passing TextView values

Tags: java, android, textview

A few days ago i asked this question but I just realised that I included the wrong logcat errors, this now contains the correct logcat...

I'm writing an app that will allow the user to enter values and they will be used to plot on a chart. The last few days I have been stuck on a particular problem and can't seem to get over it. The user will input 2 values and from these 3 values will be calculated and passed to an inner class to be plotted on the chart. These values are of the TextView form. I know most of the code works as i have been testing it, and i'm pretty sure that the error has something to do with the TextView values. Below is the code used for the calculations and drawing the chart.

```
package com.example.ballanimation;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class calculations extends Activity {

EditText firstVal, secondVal;
TextView resultA, resultB, resultC;
Button button3;
BigDecimal firstNum, secNum;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.calculations_page);

button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

firstVal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTXT1);
secondVal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTXT2);

resultA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result1);
resultB = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result2);
resultC = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result3);


button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        firstNum = new BigDecimal(firstVal.getText().toString());
        secNum = new BigDecimal(secondVal.getText().toString());
        resultA.setText(firstNum.add(secNum).toString());
        resultB.setText(firstNum.subtract(secNum).toString());
        resultC.setText(firstNum.multiply(secNum).toString());

    }
});


}

class TestA1 extends View{

public TestA1(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    String TestA = resultA.getText().toString();
    String TestB = resultB.getText().toString();
    String TestC = resultC.getText().toString();

    int A = Integer.parseInt(TestA);
    int B = Integer.parseInt(TestB);
    int C = Integer.parseInt(TestC);

    Paint red = new Paint();
    red.setColor(Color.RED);
    red.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    Paint black = new Paint();
    black.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    black.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    canvas.drawCircle(A, B, C, black);
    canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()*1/2, canvas.getHeight()*3/8,    canvas.getWidth()*475/1000, black);
    canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()*5/8, canvas.getWidth()*5/8, canvas.getWidth()*349/1000, black);
    canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()*6/8, canvas.getWidth()*5/8, canvas.getWidth()*228/1000, black);
    canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()*7/8, canvas.getWidth()*5/8, canvas.getWidth()*103/1000, black);

    canvas.drawLine((canvas.getWidth()-canvas.getWidth()) + 10, (canvas.getHeight()*3)/8, canvas.getWidth() - 10, (canvas.getHeight()*3)/8, black);

    float a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l;

    a = 90;   //degrees
    b = 90;
    c = 90;
    d = 50;
    e = 90;
    f = 134;
    g = -90;
    h = -90;
    i = -90;
    j = -50;
    k = -90;
    l = -134;

    RectF arc0 = new RectF();
    RectF arc1 = new RectF();
    RectF arc2 = new RectF();
    RectF arc3 = new RectF();
    RectF arc4 = new RectF();
    RectF arc5 = new RectF();

    /*left  The X coordinate of the left side of the rectangle 
    top  The Y coordinate of the top of the rectangle 
    right  The X coordinate of the right side of the rectangle 
    bottom  The Y coordinate of the bottom of the rectangle  */



    arc0.set(canvas.getWidth()*1/2, canvas.getHeight()*-139/700, canvas.getWidth()*100/69, canvas.getHeight()*3/8); 
    arc1.set(canvas.getWidth()*-6/112, canvas.getHeight()*-80/100, canvas.getWidth()*195/100, canvas.getHeight()*72/192);   
    arc2.set(canvas.getWidth()*7/10, canvas.getHeight()*70/700, canvas.getWidth()*125/100, canvas.getHeight()*3/8); 
    arc3.set(canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()*3/8, canvas.getWidth()*100/69, canvas.getHeight()*91/96);
    arc4.set(canvas.getWidth()*-8/112, canvas.getHeight()*3/8, canvas.getWidth()*195/100, canvas.getHeight()*150/100);
    arc5.set(canvas.getWidth()*7/10, canvas.getHeight()*3/8, canvas.getWidth()*125/100, canvas.getHeight()*65/100);


    /*oval  The bounds of oval used to define the shape and size of the arc 
    startAngle  Starting angle (in degrees) where the arc begins 
    sweepAngle  Sweep angle (in degrees) measured clockwise 
    useCenter  If true, include the center of the oval in the arc, and close it if it is being stroked. This will draw a wedge 
    paint  The paint used to draw the arc  */

    canvas.drawArc(arc0, a, b, false, red);
    canvas.drawArc(arc1, c, d, false, red);
    canvas.drawArc(arc2, e, f, false, red);
    canvas.drawArc(arc3, g, h, false, red);
    canvas.drawArc(arc4, i, j, false, red);
    canvas.drawArc(arc5, k, l, false, red);

}
}
}
```

The Logcat errors I am getting are:

```
01-08 11:54:05.436: D/dalvikvm(714): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 42K, 3% free 8053K/8259K, paused 66ms, total 69ms
01-08 11:54:05.436: I/dalvikvm-heap(714): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.305MB for 412064-byte allocation
01-08 11:54:05.596: D/dalvikvm(714): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 3% free 8455K/8711K, paused 55ms, total 55ms
01-08 11:54:05.647: D/dalvikvm(714): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 3% free 8455K/8711K, paused 48ms, total 48ms
01-08 11:54:05.666: I/dalvikvm-heap(714): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.189MB for 928216-byte allocation
01-08 11:54:05.836: D/dalvikvm(714): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 4% free 9361K/9671K, paused 98ms+9ms, total 173ms
01-08 11:54:05.836: D/dalvikvm(714): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 3ms
01-08 11:54:06.186: D/gralloc_goldfish(714): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
01-08 11:54:07.856: I/Choreographer(714): Skipped 79 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-08 11:54:25.786: D/AndroidRuntime(714): Shutting down VM
01-08 11:54:25.816: W/dalvikvm(714): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
01-08 11:54:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(714): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-08 11:54:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(714): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-08 11:54:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at com.example.ballanimation.calculations$TestA1.onDraw(calculations.java:83)
01-08 11:54:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13458)
01-08 11:54:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13342)
01-08 11:54:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
01-08 11:54:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
01-08 11:54:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13461)
01-08 11:54:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
01-08 11:54:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13342)
01-08 11:54:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
01-08 11:54:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
01-08 11:54:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13340)
01-08 11:54:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
01-08 11:54:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
01-08 11:54:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13461)
01-08 11:54:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
01-08 11:54:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2183)
01-08 11:54:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.drawSoftware(ViewRootImpl.java:2256)
01-08 11:54:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2151)
01-08 11:54:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2019)
01-08 11:54:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1830)
01-08 11:54:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
01-08 11:54:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
01-08 11:54:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
01-08 11:54:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
01-08 11:54:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
01-08 11:54:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
01-08 11:54:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-08 11:54:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-08 11:54:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-08 11:54:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-08 11:54:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-08 11:54:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-08 11:54:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-08 11:54:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-08 11:54:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-08 11:54:28.535: I/Process(714): Sending signal. PID: 714 SIG: 9
```

I'm pretty sure the error is contained in the line's:

```
                    String TestA = resultA.getText().toString();
        String TestB = resultB.getText().toString();
        String TestC = resultC.getText().toString();
```

There must be something wrong with the way I am passing the TextView values, but I can't see where the problem is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `NullPointerException 01-08 11:54:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(714): at com.example.ballanimation.calculations$TestA1.onDraw(calculations.java:83)`  Which is line 83 in your onDraw() function?

Comment: @ what you contain on this line `calculations.java:83`?

Comment: @PratikSharma  hi thanks for responding, line 83 contains:        String TestA = resultA.getText().toString();
        String TestB = resultB.getText().toString();
        String TestC = resultC.getText().toString();

Comment: @user1927105 Okay. try with the solution I have posted below.

Comment: @PratikSharma no its still force closing once I hit the button to do the calculations. As far as I can see it's giving me the same logcat errors

Comment: Did u try renaming your classname as a capital "C" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this :

```
        String TestA="",TestB="",TestC="";

        if(!resultA.getText().toString().equals("")) 
            TestA = resultA.getText().toString();
        if(!resultB.getText().toString().equals("")) 
            TestB = resultB.getText().toString();
        if(!resultC.getText().toString().equals("")) 
            TestC = resultC.getText().toString();
```

Instead Of :

```
        String TestA = resultA.getText().toString();
        String TestB = resultB.getText().toString();
        String TestC = resultC.getText().toString();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your class name "calculations" starts with small letter and suppose it should start with a capital "C".

Comment: I think this should be a comment. But I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

```
String TestA = resultA.getText().toString();
String TestB = resultB.getText().toString();
String TestC = resultC.getText().toString();
```

put this code outside your TestA1 Class and use this variables inside your class.
and you are done.hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi here couple of reasons possible for NullPointerException

1) First the String in the text view might not have entered and.

2) Second the id's (`R.id.result1, R.id.result2, R.id.result3`) of the respective text view might not present in the same layout(`R.layout.calculations_page`) which you have using in the activity

For 1st scenario you can go with Pratik Sharma's advice

For 2nd check for null `resultA, resultB, resultC`

e.g

```
if(resultA!=null){
}
```